# npm install -g working fine, npm install throwing error "npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/storybook__addon-knobs - Not found"

Tags: npm-install

npm install -g working fine, all the modules for the same package.json is getting installed.

npm install is throwing error for the same package.json. below is the error
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/storybook__addon-knobs - Not found